# Build team for a project using PSI

Tags: c#, psi

I am new to PSI coding.... 
I have created a project , I need to build a team for that project .... resource must be existing in a project server .... I researched but i couldn't get what i want 
How to do it...??

```
 WbSvcProject.ProjectDataSet pds = new WbSvcProject.ProjectDataSet();

            Guid PUID = Guid.Parse("8d73de15-8f85-4c5e-8da9-de0b85f48eed");
            pds = proj.ReadProject(PUID, WbSvcProject.DataStoreEnum.WorkingStore);
```

i need to build a team for this project... resource must be existing in a project server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

old VS2010? solution. VS2012 appears to use a new way of calling the service through WbSvcProject.ProjectSoapClient()?!?

```
using Library = Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library;

class ProjectProxy
{
    private WbSvcProject.Project projectSvc;

    public ProjectProxy()
    {
        this.projectSvc = new WbSvcProject.Project();
        this.projectSvc.Url = Program.PWAServer + "/_vti_bin/psi/project.asmx";
        this.projectSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }

    //ProjectTeamDataSet ds = new ProjectTeamDataSet();
    //ProjectTeamDataSet.ProjectTeamRow row = ds.ProjectTeam.NewProjectTeamRow();
    //row.PROJ_UID = projectGuid;
    //row.RES_UID = resourceGuid;
    //row.NEW_RES_UID = resourceGuid;
    //ds.ProjectTeam.AddProjectTeamRow(row);

    public void QueueUpdateProjectTeam(Guid sessionUid, Guid projectUid, ProjectTeamDataSet dataset)
    {
        Guid jobUid = Guid.NewGuid();

        try
        {
            this.projectSvc.QueueUpdateProjectTeam(jobUid, sessionUid, projectUid, dataset);
        }
        catch (SoapException soapException)
        {
            List<string> queueErrors = new List<string>();
            queueErrors.Add(soapException.Message);
            Library.PSClientError clientError = new Library.PSClientError(soapException);
            Library.PSErrorInfo[] errors = clientError.GetAllErrors();
            foreach (Library.PSErrorInfo error in errors)
            {
                queueErrors.Add(error.ErrId.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```